# Return True if any number is even inside a list else return false

Tags: python, for-loop

I am new to Python. I am doing some exercise online.

```
def user_input_checking_even_number_list(user_input_list):
  
    for input_number in user_input_list:
        if input_number%2 == 0:
            return True
        else:
            pass
        
    return False
```

if I key run the code below

```
user_input_checking_even_number_list([1,3,5,8,9,11,20,21])
```

It will return True. But I have one question, is the for loop only check until 8 then the for loop will break? or it actually runs and checks until 21 even though the 8 is an even number that already meets the requirement?

Comment: If it finds a suitable number, it immediately returns true. That means the function is finished.

Comment: By the way, the `else: pass` is completely pointless.

Comment: The `return` statement ends the function itself. Thus ending the loop when the condition is met.

Comment: I see, thank you for your reply. Now only I realized the else : pass is useless at here.

Comment: and then you can have a look at [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

Comment: You can use [pythontutor](https://pythontutor.com/)  to visualize the execution of your program to answer questions like this.

Comment: You can use debug mode to run your code line by line, to confirm it will only check until 8 then break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time when your program was executing the statement `return True` in your code, `input_number` was `8` and `for` loop had more iterations left. But `return` statement causes this flow to break and immediately return to the code which called the function - which is outside of the function.